# Memory Optimization For Linked Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory

I recently made a script that generates random mazes, using a custom maze class, built up from several maze nodes. Each node looks like this:

```
class mazeNode:
    def __init__(self, pos, conn = None):
        self.pos = pos
        if conn:
            self.conns = [conn]
        else:
            self.conns = []
```

`conn` is another mazeNode object, and `self.conns` is changed during creation of the maze to include every mazeNode object that the node connects to. `pos` is a tuple with the position of the node. When the maze is created, mazeNode objects are created, and linked together in a branching, according to a depth-first search algorithm.

The script works very well, and can create a maze of size 500*500 in about 10 seconds. However, it doesn't seem to be very memory efficient. I have managed to create a maze of size 6000*6000, but when I try 10000*10000, I get a memory error no matter what I do, even if I allocate 50GB of Virtual RAM. For that size, I end up with 10^8 mazeNode objects.

I tried using the `shelve` module, but that slowed down the script too much to be usable, and for bigger mazes, I got a recursion depth error (maybe the script was slow because of unnecessary recursion).

I am wondering if there is any way to optimize the memory usage of the script, while retaining the speed. All the nodes are linked together, but it isn't necessary for them all to be in RAM.

EDIT
The maze class is as follows:

```
class Maze:

    def __init__(self, xSize, ySize):

        self.pos = (xSize//2, ySize//2)
        self.xSize = xSize
        self.ySize = ySize
        self.directions = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]
        self.visit = set([self.pos])
        self.maze = mazeNode(self.pos)
        self.node = self.maze
        self.stack = Stack()
        self.deadEnds = 0
        for i in randPerm(list(range(4))):
            self.stack.put(mazeNode(add(self.pos, self.directions[i]), self.node))

    def makeMaze(self):
        while True:
            while self.node.pos in self.visit and not self.stack.isEmpty():
                self.node = self.stack.pop()
            if self.stack.isEmpty():
                break
            if self.node.pos not in self.visit:
                self.visit.add(self.node.pos)

            for conn in self.node.conns:
                conn.conns.append(self.node)

            tempCount = 0
            for i in randPerm(list(range(4))):
                pos = add(self.node.pos, self.directions[i])
                if pos not in self.visit and check(pos, self.xSize, self.ySize):
                    self.stack.put(mazeNode(pos, self.node))
                    tempCount += 1
            if tempCount == 0:
                self.deadEnds += 1
        if len(self.maze.conns) == 1:
            self.deadEnds += 1
```

EDIT 2:

I used **slots**: and edited the mazeNode class as follows:

```
class mazeNode:
    __slots__ = ('posx', 'posy', 'conns', )

    def __init__(self, pos, conn = None):
        self.posx = pos[0]
        self.posy = pos[1]
        self.conns = [conn] if conn else []
```

and used `sys.getsizeof()` to get the size of an instance of the class.

```
print(sys.getsizeof(self.maze), sys.getsizeof(self.maze.posx), sys.getsizeof(self.maze.posy), sys.getsizeof(self.maze.conns))
```

prints `64 28 28 96`. However, if I remove the `__slots__`, I get `56 28 28 96`, which seems strange. How should I interpret this? Is `__slots__` not working correctly?

Comment: Could you also provide the code for the actual maze generation please?

Comment: Also, just as a side note, the `if statement` can simply be `self.conns = [conn] if conn else []`

Comment: Have you tried using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots)? That'd at least decrease per-object memory usage.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using `__slots__` since even dropping a single byte of memory allocation ends up saving 100MB if you have 10**8 objects. @xj9 has the best idea here

Comment: @xj9 I haven't heard about `__slots__`, but at first glance it looks like it could help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) are pretty simple to use, you just add them to your class definition as such:

```
class MazeNode(object):
    __slots__ = ('pos', 'conn', )

    def __init__(self, pos, conn=None):
        self.pos = pos
        self.conns = [conn] if conn else []
```

The only thing you have to remember that slotted types/classes can't have attributes added to them dynamically. Only the attributes listed in `__slots__` can be set and/or modified. Even though they *do* significantly decrease per-object memory usage, don't get crazy and define slots for every class you define. Be wise and use them justly.

Comment: I did just this, see my last edit. However, my results weren't the ones I had hoped for.